# Can you sync a device in iTunes over VPN?

Tags: itunes, vpn

If I have a home server, could I connect via VPN from any other computer and sync my device in iTunes (on the server)?

Comment: Are you trying to imitate the sync over WiFi or sync over USB?

Comment: Either one would work.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'd also need some way of forwarding your USB port **from** your local computer **to** the remote computer<sup>*1*</sup>.

There are a few commercial applications<sup>*2*</sup> that does USB over the net but a quick glance seems to indicate that they let you access USB devices on the remote computer locally and not the other way around.

<sup>*1*</sup>
<sup><sub>When you say VPN I assume you also use some kind of remote desktop software.</sub></sup>
<sup>*2*</sup> 
<sup><sub>http://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-for-remote-desktop.html  , 
http://www.incentivespro.com/usb-redirector-rdp.html</sub></sup>